# Efficient way to find degree of edge in induced subgraph?

Tags: graphs

Let **G(V,E)** be a graph and **H(V',E')** be some induced subgraph of **G**. Let **v** be a vertex from **V'**. Is there an efficient way to calculate the degree of **v** in the subgraph **H** if we have some representation of **G**? (Preferably it should be **O(1)**)

Comment: If the graph is stored in adjacency list representation, union find might be used to 'find' all neighbors in near constant time. However, counting them will then require iterating over all neighbors, so this isn't quite constant.

Comment: Can we choose how $H$ is represented?  If so, what prevents us from precomputing the degree (in $H$) of every vertex?  If not, how is $H$ represented?

Comment: @D.W. I'm sorry, I wasn't clear in what i meant. What I had in mind is, given a graph G(V,E) (represented in some way) and a subset V' of the vertices V, how can we find the degree a vertex in V' in the subgraph it induces without creating a representation for it (i.e. using only the representation we have of G)?